# Let $N\sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$ be a normal RV. Let $g$ be continuous. Can we bound $E[g(N)]$ in terms of $\sigma^2$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, upper-lower-bounds

> Let $N\sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$ be a normal RV. Let $g$ be continuous. Can we bound $E[g(N)]$ in terms of $\sigma^2$?

This seems fairly easy but it might be wrong. What if we assume additional structure on $g$? For example what if assume that $g$ is continuous convex? This is something that came up in research.

Comment: It is unlikely that such a bound exists without additional structure on $g$. Take for example, $g\equiv 0$ vs. $g(x)=\exp(x^2)1\{x>0\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, in addition, $g$ is Lipschitz with $g(0)=0$, then
\begin{align}
|\mathsf{E}g(N)|&\le |g(0)|+\mathsf{E}|g(N)-g(0)| \\
&\le |g(0)|+\operatorname{Lip}(g)\mathsf{E}|N|=\operatorname{Lip}(g)\sigma\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ and suppose that $g$ is twice differentiable with a bounded second derivative.

We will now consider the first order taylor approximation $t(x) = g(0) + g'(0)x$  around $x=0$, and we note that $\mathbb{E}[t(X)]=g(0)$. This means that

\begin{align*}
\Big|\mathbb{E}[g(X)]-g(0) \Big| &= \Big|\mathbb{E}[g(X)-t(X)] \Big| \\ &\leq \mathbb{E}\big[ \big|g(X)-t(X)|]
\end{align*}
But if the second derivative is bounded by some constant $C>0$, then taylors formula gives that
$$|g(x)-t(x)| \leq \frac{C}{2}x^2$$
and thus we get that
$$\Big|\mathbb{E}[g(X)]-g(0) \Big| \leq \frac{C}{2}\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \frac{C\sigma^2}{2}  $$